# Python while loop not ending when condition is met

Tags: python

I'm assuming the issue has to be with setting a global variable but even with my trying to fix it with that, I still can't seem to figure it out. Code is pretty rough but I only started learning <2 days ago so please bear with me. From my understanding, if the password is entered correctly, the game variable should be equal to False which should end the loop. However, it keeps going on and asking player 1 for input. Also, I can't seem to be getting the checkGame function to work properly inside the while loop.

```
board = [
0,1,2,
3,4,5,
6,7,8
]
print(board)

global counter
counter = 0

global game
game = True

def checkGame():
    if board[0] == player_1:
        print("Game won by player 1!")
        game == False

def player_1():
    player_1 = 'X'
    # return player_1
    selection = int(input("P1: Pick a position: "))
    board[selection] = player_1
    print(board)
    global game
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print("Counter = ", counter)
    print("game:", game)

def player_2():
    player_2 = "O"
    selection = int(input("P2: Pick a position: "))
    board[selection] = player_2
    print(board)
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print("Counter = ", counter)
    print("game:", game)


while game == True:

    password = input("password: ")
    if password == 'testing':
        game = False
        print(game)
    else:
        pass

    if counter == 9:
        game = False

    player_1()

    if board[0] == player_1:
        print("Game won by player 1!")
        game == False

    if counter == 9:
        game == False

    checkGame()
    player_2()

    if counter == 9:
        game == False

    checkGame()
```

Comment: `game == False` under those prints signaling that a player won does not set the value of the variable. You might've meant `game = False`

Comment: `==` check, `=` assign.   You have `==` inside the `while` loop where I think you meant to assign `False` to `game`.  Ex. after your last `if counter == 9:`, should it not be `game = False` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while loop's condition is not checked continuously, only at the start of each loop iteration. To exit the loop immediately use a `break` statement. For example, in this code it will print "Keep running" even after you type "exit"

```py
running = True
while running:
    password = input("password: ")
    if password == "exit":
        running = False # does not exit the loop, just stops the next run
        
    print("Keep running")
```

but in this code it will not

```py
running = True
while running:
    password = input("password: ")
    if password == "exit":
        break # exits the loop
        
    print("Keep running")
```

Also, unrelated to your immediate issue of not exiting on the password entry, `var == False` does not set `var` to false, it just checks if it is equal to false. Be sure to use `=` for assignment, not `==`.

You also seem to be mixing method names and variable names (e.g. `player_1`) which is probably going to cause problems...